# Merge two Java source files using Ant

Tags: ant

I want to merge two different files using Ant. How do I do it?

```
Ex a.java and B.java
```

---

```
<target name="merge">
        <property prefix="app.properties" file="input1.txt" />
        <property prefix="app.properties" file="input2.txt" />
        <echoproperties destfile="output.txt">
           <propertyset>
              <propertyref prefix="app.properties"/>
              <mapper type="glob" from="app.properties.*" to=""/>
           </propertyset>
        </echoproperties>

</target>
```

this is not working correctly

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600910/using-ant-to-merge-two-different-properties-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Ant to merge two different properties files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600910/using-ant-to-merge-two-different-properties-files)

Comment: Not Property file. I want to merge 2 java file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [concat task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html)

```
<concat destfile="output.txt">
  <fileset file="input1.txt" />
  <fileset file="input2.txt" />
</concat>
```